# How to add same hair particles settings

Tags: particles, hair

I have hair settings on the neck

[image]

I have made a new vertex group for the top head part. I want to have few hairs of same settings of the neck part. As the neck part hairs are comb and now its not editable. I tried duplicating the particles and rename on top area but cant rename below as its not editable. When change the top hair setting the neck part change. Any way to have same setting without disturbing the neck part hairs.

I tried to create a vertex group and assign.

[image]

There are no hairs still hairs are grown.

[image]

I want to add new hairs but with the neck hair settings. How it works. Any suggestion or help. Thanks